# OSRM install start osrm-routed

Tags: ubuntu, installation, osrm

I am fighting with the installation of OSRM on my ubuntu 12.04 server. on

```
osrm-routed map.osrm
```

I get the following error:

```
[info] starting up engines, v4.8.1
[info] populating base path: map.osrm
[info] HSGR file:       "map.osrm.hsgr"
[info] loading graph data
[info] loading graph from map.osrm.hsgr
[info] number_of_nodes: 13257636, number_of_edges: 91420598
[info] loaded 13257636 nodes and 91420598 edges
[info] Data checksum is 2360151423
[info] loading edge information
[info] loading core information
[info] loading geometries
[info] loading r-tree
[info] loading timestamp
[info] Loading Timestamp
[info] loading street names
[info] loaded plugin: table
[info] loaded plugin: hello
[info] loaded plugin: locate
[info] loaded plugin: nearest
[info] loaded plugin: match
[info] loaded plugin: timestamp
[info] loaded plugin: viaroute
[info] loaded plugin: trip
[info] http 1.1 compression handled by zlib version 1.2.8
[warn] [exception] bind: Address already in use
```

I tried several versions of server.ini, but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

The default port used by OSRM (port `5000`) seems to be already grabbed. You can specify a different port using:

> ./osrm-routed -p YOUR_PORT data.osrm

I would suggest not using the `server.ini` anymore, since support will be dropped in the next release. Please use the command line options instead.

Comment: Yess ... that worked. Seems server.ini allready no working. Changed the the port there but without effect.